# I am having issue with django web application deployment on ubuntu VPS. The issue is that the server do not give any response even on 0.0.0.0:8000

Tags: python, django, apache, gunicorn, ubuntu-18.04

While deploying the Django website everything goes right but when I run the command ***python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000*** then the server starts successfully but then if I try the
***IP:8000*** on the browser, it shows the site can't be reached and even no computation executes on the server terminal of Django.
I have executed

```
sudo ufw allow 8000
```

but still, the error is the same.

I have tried **apache** and **nginx** but got the same output for both.

I am following this guide

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04

also tried:

- https://www.codewithharry.com/blogpost/django-deploy-nginx-gunicorn

I am using VPS having 1 core, 0.5 GB RAM, Data transfer rate:400 Mbps, I am wondering if Django's requirements for running the application are not met.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after going through [this](https://github.com/mitchtabian/HOWTO-django-channels-daphne#update-headerhtml) tutorial. It turned out that ufw simply wasn't running by default. Check by `ufw status`, start with `sudo ufw enable`

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](/help/deleted-answers).